# How to specify Docker Hub token scope

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm trying to create an access token for a specifc docker hub repo ( a repo I created and made public on my hub.docker account)

I dont want a full access token.

The goal is to create a script that pushes an image to that repo using an access token that is limited to this repo only.

I've read the documentation but still lost
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can't then. https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/ doesn't imply any scoping. Could you create an account that's a collaborator on that one repo, then create an access token for that service account?

Comment: Thats a good idea, but I saw this and was confused but maybe the registry is something else? 

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/scope/ 

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/